# About the KVO reference count

Tags: ios, key-value-observing

When I use

```
addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:
```

In this method, will the observer be a strong reference or just a weak reference in ARC?

Any ideas for this problematic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html)

> Note: The key-value observing addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:
>   method does not maintain strong references to the observing object,
>   the observed objects, or the context. You should ensure that you
>   maintain strong references to the observing, and observed, objects,
>   and the context as necessary.

In short: The method does not maintain a strong reference to the observer.